# CSS Border Transition adds Unwanted Extra Pixels

Tags: html, css, sass, electron, css-transitions

I am styling a button for my electron application (HTML, SASS). On hover, this button will add a 10px border-top and border-bottom, then adjust its height by -20 to cancel out extra border height. I have the transition working *almost* perfectly except for when a small border (less than 1px it seems) is added to each border(top and bottom on hover), this additional border increases the total height of the button just enough to push the downstream html in a little bump that is pretty visually annoying. In the included gif you will notice it most when the hover-off transition is finished, you should see a 1px border just disappear abruptly at the end. How can I prevent this extra few pixels of border from generating and bumping the rest of my html around? Any other way to create the same effect I am going for?

This is my second post here, the last was close to 2 years ago, so please let me know if I am missing something that I should have included, thanks for reading!

HTML:

```
<div class="--square e--block --btn">
    <h1>Create Backups</h1>                    
</div>
```

SCSS Variables:

```
$mainSize: 100px;
$btnBorder: 10px;
```

SCSS:

```
//-- Basic element
.e--block {
    //-- Position
    //- Flex
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    //- Text
    text-align: center;
    //- Align
    margin: $baseSpacing;

    //-- Style
    //- BG
    background-color: $btnColorLight;
    //- Text
    color: $white;
    font-weight: 2;
    //- Border
    //border: none;
    border-radius: $borderRadius;

    
    * {
        //-- Position
        //- Flex
        vertical-align: middle;
        //- Align
        padding: {
            top: 10px;
            bottom: 10px;
        }
        margin: auto;
    }
}

.--btn {
    //-- Style
    //- Border
    border: 0px solid white;
    //- Transition
    transition: {
        property: border-width, height;
        duration: 1s;
        timing-function: ease;
    }
}
.--square {
    //-- Position
    //- Size
    height: ($mainSize * 2);
    width: ($mainSize * 2);
}
.--btn.--square:hover:not(.--no-trans) {
    //-- Position
    //- Size
    height: (($mainSize * 2) - ($btnBorder * 2));
    //-- Style
    //- Border
    border-top-width: $btnBorder;
    border-bottom-width: $btnBorder;
}
```

[image: Visual of the problem]

Comment: Could you put up a working snippet, that will help us look at the problem more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain why this problem is happening but I would guess it's because the rendering engine is bad at handling this kind of double transitions.

As a workaround you can had a [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property with `border-box` value on your `.--square` and remove the `height` change:

```
.--square {
   //-- Position
   //- Size
   height: ($mainSize * 2);
   width: ($mainSize * 2);
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.--btn.--square:hover:not(.--no-trans) {
    //-- Position
    //- Size
    //-- Style
    //- Border
    border-top-width: $btnBorder;
    border-bottom-width: $btnBorder;
}
```

Comment: This mostly worked, getting rid of the annoying content bump, though that weird 1px final frame is still there. By using layered inset box-shadows : 
(box-shadow: 0 0px white inset, 0 0px white inset) 
(box-shadow: 0 -10px white inset, 0 10px white inset) :hover
I was able to accomplish that border style much smoother, no weird 1px final frame.
Thank you so much! Hope this whole thing helps anyone else having the same issue.

Comment: Hum yes, I don't know if there is a little hack existing to fix this 1px problem. Sometimes it can be solved by ading a property like `transform` but I couldn't make it work here. The `box-shadow` solution is a nice trick!

Comment: Maybe you should post your solution as an answer and accept it instead?

Answer (score 0):

Also I think you can somewhat fasten up this bump by using custom `timing-function`, for example:

`transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.18, 0.89, 0.32, 1.28);`